Block GetMapping util get message from Redis in Spring boot
I'm having two services, Service A and Service B, using Redis for inter-service communication.

Service A using Spring boot.


Service B using expressjs (it seems like a consumer, consume message then publish a message notify to service A that "Hey service A, I'm done")

Service A should expose two endpoints: /api-publish and /api-consume. When a user makes a request to the /api-publish endpoint, Service A should publish a message to a Redis topic named topic1.
Service B should be set up to consume messages from topic1. Upon successful processing of a message from topic1, Service B should then publish a message to another Redis topic named topic2.
All I want to make a request to the /api-consume endpoint on Service A, the service should wait until Service B has successfully published a message to topic2. Only then should Service A return a response to the user.
Here is my Redis configuration in service A:
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.data.redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<?, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(new RedisMessageSubscriber());
    }

    @Bean
    ChannelTopic topic() {
        return new ChannelTopic("topic2");
    }

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer redisContainer() {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container
                = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory());
        container.addMessageListener(messageListener(), topic());
        return container;
    }

}

Here is service that get message from topic2:
@Service
public class RedisMessageSubscriber implements MessageListener {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
        String receivedMessage = new String(message.getBody());
        try {
            queue.put(receivedMessage);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public String waitForMessage(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return queue.poll(timeout, unit);
    }
}

Here is a simple controller:
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> template;
    @Autowired
    private RedisMessageSubscriber subscriber;

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/public/test")
    public String test() {
        try {
            String message = subscriber.waitForMessage(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (message != null) {
                return "Received message from Service B: " + message;
            } else {
                return "Timeout waiting for message from Service B";
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return "Failed to receive message";
        }
    }
}


I've already edited my question

Even then the question is still not very focused. "ensure that messages are not lost in the process and handle potential errors or exceptions that might occur during the publish/subscribe operations. Consider edge cases such as what should happen if Service B is down or if it takes too long to process a message." Do you have any idea how broad and vague this is?

sorry because I don't know keyword to describe. I removed it

All I want to make a request to the /api-consume endpoint on Service A, the service should wait until Service B has successfully published a message to topic2. Only then should Service A return a response to the user. I've already use expressjs for Service A before and I use eventEmitter. When Service A got message from topic, I will emit an event and in controller, I listen that event. But in Spring boot I don't know how to do this.

Yes, and whats wrong with your current code? Is it not working? How is it not working? If you want it to wait until a message is published you should just use the poll() method without timeouts

I call waitForMessage method in controller, but when I call api in postman, request was hangout without return any response., it loads forever

Can you put a break point in your waitForMessage method and see where it hangs forever during debugging?

yes. I put a break point in both controller and waitForMessage, onMessage method. When I start to call api, first it comes to controller -> waitForMessage. In waitForMessage method, queue is empty, when I publish a message in redis-cli, nothing happened in waitForMessage method, queue is still empty

I suspect you have 2 instances of RedisMessageSubscriber.
Your controller injects @Service annotated one, but the messages come to the:
@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(new RedisMessageSubscriber()); // <--- this one
}

So, in order to use only one instance you have to:

Drop the @Service annotation off RedisMessageSubscriber
Slightly adjust the RedisConfig like this:

@Bean
public RedisMessageSubscriber redisMessageSubscriber() {
    return new RedisMessageSubscriber();
} 

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter messageListener() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(redisMessageSubscriber());
}


But if I don't init RedisMessageSubscriber in MessageListenerAdapter, it will be error because MessageListenerAdapter accept a MessageListener

I see.  In RedisMessageSubscriber I add @Service so Spring get it as a bean. Also I init new RedisMessageSubscriber() so I have 2 instances running. But, how can I know ensure that messages are not lost in the process and handle potential errors or exceptions that might occur during the publish/subscribe operations? Also Consider edge cases such as what should happen if Service B is down or if it takes too long to process a message.
